# Cannot create or update posts using php v3 library ((403) We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource.')

Tags: php, blogger, google-api-php-client

I use the Blogger library v3 for php,I can not insert a new post.

The error message was:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3631076204866601722/posts: (403) We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource.' in E:\xampp\htdocs\Udemy2Blogger\libs\Google\Http\REST.php:79
Stack trace:
 #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\Udemy2Blogger\libs\Google\Http\REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
 #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\Udemy2Blogger\libs\Google\Client.php(508): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
 #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\Udemy2Blogger\libs\Google\Service\Resource.php(195): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
 #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\Udemy2Blogger\libs\Google\Service\Blogger.php(1495): Google_Service_Resource->call('insert', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
 #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\Udemy2Blogger\index.php(78): Google_Service_Blogger_Posts_Resource->insert('363107620486660...', Object(Google_Service_Blogger_Post), Array)
 #5 {main} thrown inE:\xampp\htdocs\Udemy2Blogger\libs\Google\Http\REST.php on line 79
```

the code is:

```
<?php

session_start();
$path = "libs";
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Blogger.php';

$blogId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$service_account_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$key_file_location = 'udemy coupon free-e0de16bee449.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApplicationName("Udemy coupon free");

$bloggerService = new Google_Service_Blogger($client);

/************************************************
  If we have an access token, we can carry on.
  Otherwise, we'll get one with the help of an
  assertion credential. In other examples the list
  of scopes was managed by the Client, but here
  we have to list them manually. We also supply
  the service account
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key1 = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'),
    $key1
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$newpost = new Google_Service_Blogger_Post();
$newpost->setTitle("test");
$newpost->setContent("test content");

$post = $bloggerService->posts->insert($blogId, $newpost, array());


print_r($post);
```

Enable Blogger Api v3:

[image: Enable Blogger Api v3]

Create client id (service account):

[image: Create client id (service account) 1]

[image: Create client id (service account) 2]

Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: the service account needs to have access to the blogger account or it cant access it.

Comment: Thanks, How to config service account to access blogger account? I can't see anything about it in blogger settings.

Comment: try and add the service account email as a Blog Author, under settings -> basic  (No idea if it will work.)

Comment: Thanks, I've followed the instructions: http://www.designerblogs.com/granting-access-to-blogger-blog/ but I don't known how to check invite email (service account email) ?

Comment: You can't check it's email it's not really an account.   tbh i am not sure you can use a service account with the blogger api.

Comment: I don`t know why but i trying do the same and after a copule of hours Your code work so thanks for posting this peace of code here! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've successful after switching to use Client ID (Web application) instead of using Client ID (Service account).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if the google blogger ID doesn't match then you might get this error. You can find the blogger ID in the URL of the blogger account.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same via REST client. Seems like service account didn't have permission to add blogger posts.

> The reason might be - Only an author/admin can create/edit Posts and
>   service email can't be added to this list.

[Attached ARC screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPVoY.png)